# Ruby - negative condition in while statement

Tags: ruby, while-loop, conditional-statements

RubyMine warns me about negative condition here:

```
while !open_socket do
    sleep 1
end
```

I know that `unless` is an opposite to `if`, but what is the opposite to `while` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is `until`:

```
until open_socket do
    sleep 1
end
```

If there is only one line in it, you could also write as:

```
sleep 1 until open_socket
```